# 8601 ISO String to readable date format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, variables, time, timezone

I'm having a pretty horrid time trying to convert an 8601 into a readable format. The date shows as 'P0DT0H0M10S' and is stored in a var called timeLeft. Every article I find online tells me how to turn dates INTO the 8601 format, but not the other way around.

I tried using moment.js but that seems to revolve around the current date and not one set by my timeLeft var. How do I get this var into a user-friendly format? Thanks

Comment: That string does not look like ISO 8601 format. That format involves dates that look like `2010-01-01T05:06:07`.

Comment: It is a [duration format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)...

Comment: @epascarello ah OK.  Well in that case I'm not sure what it means to transform a time duration into a Date instance. I guess you could get a date relative to some other date offset by the duration, which I guess may be what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @Pointy You would get a date from 0 (potentially even year 0, day 0, time 0). Adding that to today's date should give you a reasonable future date, but it's certainly not the best solution.

Comment: @ssube I guess you could, but that's not what that format is supposed to mean. I guess you could use it to represent the duration of time between 1 Jan 0 to now :)

Answer (score 1):

Moment has a [duration type](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/):

```js
var duration = moment.duration('P1Y2M3DT4H5M6S');
// user-friendly format
var out = duration.humanize();

snippet.log(out);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, that's not an [ISO-8601 date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (not even close).

Second, [momentjs does support parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) a string into a moment, with the `moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD")` syntax (from their [front page examples](http://momentjs.com/)).

I'm not sure what the pattern you need would be, but maybe something like `[P]D[DT]H[H]M[M]S[S]`.

Comment: @epascarello Good catch. I'm going to call semantics and say they're still not dates, as such. Moment should still be able to parse them and may be able to do something meaningful, when combined with the current or another date.